# AngularJS - ngclick on 2 clicks not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I am trying to implement a simple ng-click for when a user clicks on a link in the first instance something is shown, in the second instance, the same thing that was shown is now hidden.

Here is my html:

```
<table>
<tbody ng-repeat-start="history in HistoryByCategory.HistoryByCategory[key]">
    <tr>
        <th>{{ history.CompanyName}}</th>
        <td ng-repeat="storyone in history.Histories.slice(1, 12)">
                {{ storyone.value }}
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-repeat-end>
    <tr>
        <th ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"><a>13 - 24 months</a>

            <!-- <div ng-show="collapsed">
            When placed ng-show in here, shows/hides fine.
            </div> -->

        </th>

        <td ng-repeat="historyone in history.Histories.slice(12, 24)" ng-show="collapsed">
            {{ historyone.value }}
        </td>                               
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

From the above, when a user clicks on:

```
<th ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"><a>13 - 24 months</a></th>
```

The following should be shown/hidden:

```
<td ng-repeat="historyone in history.Histories.slice(12, 24)" ng-show="collapsed">
            {{ historyone.value }}
        </td>
```

However this doesnt work.

Yet, if i place:

```
<div ng-show="collapsed">
            When placed ng-show in here, shows/hides fine.
            </div>
```

Inside my `tr`, this `DIV` shows and hides.

Comment: Please make a working fiddle or plunker, it'll take a few moments to answer it with working code

Comment: @maurycy: How very nice and big-hearted of you :) @ OamPsy: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Ukt9C/

Comment: @ExpertSystem - Thanks, i noticed in your example you didnt have the tag of ng-modal. I took this out of my application and i worked, not sure why this could impact it though. How can i accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: @OamPsy: I removed it because it doesn't make any sense (a `<th>` can't have a model associated to it). But it shouldn't make any difference. The same code works just as good **with** the `ngModel`: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Ukt9C/3/

Comment: You can't accept a comment as an answer, @ExpertSystem needs to copy the comment out into an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive with the help of jquery: the effect [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):

```
  .directive('showhide', function ( ) {
    return {
      showhide: "=",
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var link = $('th');
            link.click(function() {
                $('td').slideToggle('slow');
            });     
      }
    };
  })
```

or a "scope" variable ("show" for example) to store visibility:

```
<th ng-click="show=!show"><a>13 - 24 months</a></th>

<div ng-if="show">
    <td ng-repeat="historyone in history.Histories.slice(12, 24)"> {{ historyone.value }} </td>
<div>
```